# svn Unavailable on MYSYS2?

Tags: bash, svn, visual-studio-code

I've set up a bash terminal in VisualStudio Code (MYSYS2) and installed TortoiseSVN but I'm still unable to use SVN commands in the bash terminal. My cmd terminal through Windows 10 recognizes svn just fine. Any tips? If you need additional information just ask. I can see it in my [path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioHoO.png) as well so I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: But can you see it in the `PATH` environment variable inside the VS terminal? Probably they are not the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure how to access that

Comment: You said it is a bash terminal so you should type `echo $PATH`

On a regular Windows terminal would be `echo %PATH%`

Comment: Okay that returned the path to me. How do I go about adding svn to it

Comment: I'm not really familiar with MYSYS2, but it seems to be a kind of Linux distribution for Windows, right? Is this one: https://www.msys2.org/ ? so you may not be able to run the svn program you installed in windows and will have to install the svn client for that distribution.
Anyway, what kind of paths did the PATH variable show. Do they look like Windows paths (C:\... etc)?
If so you can append to PATH by doing `export PATH=%PATH%:C:\path\to\svn`

Comment: I typed that in, but now when I echo the path, that path is the only one that shows up. That tells me every other path was overwritten

Comment: Oh sorry, I used the incorect syntax, is $PATH. Also I don't mean literally C:\path\to\svn, but the one you showed in the image. So it should be export PATH=$PATH:"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin". Now to recover the original path I think you should just close and reopen the terminal

Comment: Okay, so that pathway IS listed in my path. But still doesn't recognize svn

Comment: Not sure. My guess is that that console cannot run Windows programs. As a final attempt you may try running the program by typing the full path to it `"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"`. Otherwise, if that terminal is actually the msys2 of the link I posted in a previous comment it may be possible to install svn there with the command `pacman -S subversion` https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Using-packages

Comment: It's not recognizing pacman either..... Edit: I fixed that lmao